# How do I query for a specific uuid in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to query for a `uuid` in my `Postgres` db.  Here is my table schema:

```
        Column        |      Type       |              Modifiers              
----------------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------
 casefile_id          | uuid            | not null default uuid_generate_v1()
 org_id               | uuid            | 
 casefile_template_id | uuid            | 
 casefile_status      | casefile_status |
```

I try to query with

`select * from casefile where casefile_id = 'e0da8698-32e6-11e7-a8de-985aeb8b64f';`

And get the error:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "e0da8698-32e6-11e7-a8de-985aeb8b64f"`

I then look on SO and see this syntax:

`select * from casefile where casefile_id = ANY('{e0da8698-32e6-11e7-a8de-985aeb8b64f}');`

But still get the error:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "e0da8698-32e6-11e7-a8de-985aeb8b64f"`

What am I missing?  How do I filter by `UUID`?  Why can't I query as I would any other primary key?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: How did you populate this table?

Comment: 9.5.2.  I populated the table with an `express` endpoint.  The uuid was created with this data type on the table `UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1()`.

Comment: That last group needs to be 12 character - you only have 11

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have wrong UUID - it misses one symbol in last symbols group